# Gerund or infinitive after "do something like"?

Tags: gerunds, infinitives

Using the following sentences as an example.

This is what happens when you do something stupid like stealing a baby unicorn.

This is what happens when you do something stupid like steal a baby unicorn.

When you do something like stealing a baby unicorn, you only make yourself a target.

When you do something like steal a baby unicorn, you only make yourself a target.

Which version is more idiomatic?

Can both be used without changing the meaning?

I've searched the web for answers, but it seems both constructions are used.

Comment: Not a very nice subject to talk about, @Locochon

Comment: Why not? Asking about gerunds and verbs' usage seems a perfectly fine topic to me, @BillJ  Care to explain?

Comment: I'm not talking about stealing babies. I'm asking about what's more natural in these kinds of sentences.

Comment: The subject matter of your examples is of a highly controversial nature. Try something neutral like "stealing cars".

Comment: Well, I'm reading a story about the mafia, who kidnap and stuff, so I'm just pulling some examples from there. Now if you would rather I typed more children-friendly examples so I get my question about grammar answered, I will.